# Excel Conditional Formatting Rows with Formula unique to each row

Tags: excel

***[Photo of Spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRbVF.png)***

What I'm basically trying to do is have the cell `E15` turn red when the percentage in `J15` is less than or greater to 20%, and the cell `K15` has the text: `Plate`.

I also want this effect to happen with all the cells in `E15-E34`, but for them to be based on their individual row. So, for example, `E18` would turn red when `K18` says: `Plate` and `J18` is less than or greater to 20%. I don't know if I'm just going about this the wrong way, but if not, then how can I achieve what I need to?

I've tried removing the `$` but they automatically reappear, any help would be greatly appreciated. See conditional formatting formula below. Photo of spreadsheet at beginning of text.

```
=AND(K15="Plate",J15>=20)
```

Column K is a selection of either `Plate` or `Stiffener` and Column J is a percentage based off a calculation of another cell.

Comment: Add formulas as plain text please.

Comment: Just change to **J15>0.2** or **J15>20%** if you meant **greater than 20%**, or to  **J15<=0.2** or **J15<=20%** if you meant **less than or equal**, or to **J15<>0.2** or **J15<>20%** if you meant what you kind of (**less than or greater** (to?) **than**) wrote.

Comment: I need it to calculate differently based on the value of K whether it is a Plate or Stiffener in which case it would be J15>0.25 for a stiffener.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

In my above photo, I have setup a conditional format with two actions (ignore my values in the photo, and follow these steps).

First, Select Cell K15 to K19 (it is important to start at K15, or else you will have to modify the formula below).

Next, add a Conditional Format formula (below). Any cell reference within this formula MUST be relative to the K15 cell.

`=IF($K15="Plate", AND($K15="Plate",$J15>=0.2), AND($K15="Stiffener", $J15>=0.25))`

You could also use this bit of code which is much more flexible, as you can expand the number of items.

`=OR(AND($K15="Plate", $J15>=0.2), AND($K15="Stiffener", $J15>=0.25))`

Comment: Thanks now my only thing is will the conditional formatting highlight cells based off the cells in their row or from row 15 because I need it to highlight based off the values in its own row. Whenever I try to apply the formatting to other cells it uses K15 and J15 still in the conditional formatting formula but I want it to use the K17 & J17 for example values.

Comment: I have modified my answer above to help you out with conditional formatting a bit more.

Pretty much you need to make sure that the cell references within your formula. (i.e. if your selection starts at K1, then your code within the "Conditional Formatting" section must start with K1)

Here is more information about conditional formatting...https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-formulas-with-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f

Comment: I haven't really fully understood although your formula made much more sense than what I was trying to do initially thanks for the help. I don't know if maybe its that I'm not starting at the first cell like K1 for example because there's a title in the way why I'm not seeing the results I want but I've found out that copy and pasting works to transfer the conditional formatting as I want it to be. Once again thanks everyone for the help.